# Identify which Chrome extension an http request is coming from in chrome console

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have this screenshot which shows the following request as failing:

[[image]

<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yI36.png)

```
Request URL:chrome-extension://cahedbegdkagmcjfolhdlechbkeaieki/jquery.min.map
Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.
Referer:http://myjoomladomain.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_menus&view=items
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
   **Chrome/32.0.1700.107** Safari/537.36
X-Source-Map-Request-From:inspector
```

It is send from one of my 50 or so extensions.

How can I identify the extension sending the failed request and remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open `chrome://extensions/`.
2. Enable **Developer mode**:

   [image]
3. Search for `cahedbegdkagmcjfolhdlechbkeaieki` (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) and you should find the extension.